# Find a set of elements with minimal costs that contains at least one element of given subsets

Tags: sets

I have encountered at my work currently a problem where I want to find an efficient algorithm for, although I suspect this might be hard problem. Maybe you can help me to tell if this is a NP hard problem or hint me to an algorithm.

When looking for similar problems, I found the hitting set problem. But my problem is a little bit different:

There is collection T of elements which each has some costs assigned. Also there are multiple subsets of T called S_n. I now want to find another subset of T called H, that contains at least one element of each S_n and where the sum of the costs of all elements in H is minimal.

Comment: Look up hitting set. It's NP-complete even with unit costs. You can see that it's quite similar to vertex cover where the sets are the edges and you have to cover all sets.